# Realizar 2 consultas en diferentes tablas y mostrar en HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas y necesito realizar 2 consultas, cada una a una tabla y resultados diferentes y mostrar los resultados en una misma tabla de HTML, estoy usando mysql, PHP y html. La primer consulta logro realizarla sin problema, pero la segunda no.
Si hago 2 consultas separadas con sql1, sql2 no logro meter ambos resultados en la misma tabla de HTML.

EDIT: Agrego el describe de mis 2 tablas. En la tabla de HTML quiero que se muestren los campos de tabla existencias que son SKU, NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION y Precio y la segunda tabla de movimientos necesito que sume de cierto sku todas las cantidades y me las imprima en la misma tabla de HTML en el campo de STOCK.

```
    <?php
    include 'conexion.php';
    include 'cabezera.html';


    $sku=$_POST['sku'];

 ?>
        <center>  
                <h3>Movimientos Producto: <?php echo $sku?></h3>        
             <table border="1">             
                <td>SKU</td>
                <td>NOMBRE</td>
                <td>DESCRIPCION</td>
                <td>PRECIO</td>
                <td>STOCK</td>


             <?php 
             $consulta="SELECT * FROM existencias WHERE sku='$sku'";
             $consulta2="SELECT sku, SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE sku='$sku'";
             $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
             $resultado2=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
             ?>       
                <tr>                
                    <td><?php echo $row['sku']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nombre']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['precio']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['stock']?></td>

               </tr>   
    <?php

        }

    ?>      
             </table>
        </center> 


    <?php 


?>
```

```
MariaDB [abarrotes]> describe movimientos;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sku           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nombre        | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descripcion   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fecha_entrada | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fecha_salida  | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cantidad      | int(14)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.021 sec)
```

```
MariaDB [abarrotes]> describe existencias;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sku         | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nombre      | varchar(25)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descripcion | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| costo       | decimal(14,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| precio      | decimal(14,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stock       | int(15)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.014 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo en una sola consulta obteniendo la cantidad en una subconsulta de movimientos

ejemplo:

```
$consulta="SELECT existencias.*, (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE movimientos.sku=existencias.sku) as cantidad FROM existencias where existencias.sku='$sku'"
```

Comment: Me arroja este error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventarios\consulta_existencias.php on line 25

Comment: había faltado agregar coma en existencias.*,

Comment: Ya no manda error, pero no me esta mostrando el resultado de la segunda consulta en mi tabla de html, solo me aparece la primer consulta.

Comment: se supone que la segunda consulta es para obtener la suma de movimientos, este ya se esta obteniendo ya que tienen relacion con el campo sku

Comment: Así es, la segunda consulta es a la tabla de movimientos que sume todos los valores que están en cantidad, únicamente de cierto sku y el total lo imprima en la tabla HTML en la columna  de Stock.

Comment: @JuanCarlosHdz, diría que lo único que esta "mal" es que deberías cambiar el alias de la sub-consulta a `stock`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una consulta anidada,

**Cambiar esto:**

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM existencias WHERE sku='$sku'";
$consulta2="SELECT sku, SUM(cantidad) FROM movimientos WHERE sku='$sku'";
```

**Por esto:**

```
$consulta = "SELECT m.sku, m.SUM(cantidad), primerConsulta.* from movimientos as m, (SELECT * FROM existencias WHERE sku = '$sku') as primerConsulta";
```

**De esta forma tu código PHP quearía así**

```
<?php 
  $consulta = "SELECT m.sku, m.SUM(cantidad), primerConsulta.* from movimientos as m, (SELECT * FROM existencias WHERE sku = '$sku') as primerConsulta";

  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
```

Comment: Intente con la opción que me das pero marca este error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventarios\consulta_existencias.php on line 24